# Converting Varchar "Time" to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A new software release has me rebuilding most of my reports. The new release is storing time as a `varchar(17)` in the following format `DDDD:HH:MM:SS.sss`. Previously the same data was stored in seconds.  I need to perform calculations on the data stored as `varchar` but a classic `CONVERT(TIME, *THIS_FIELD*)` results in the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I have also tried `CAST()` with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a data type that supports storing time spans/intervals. It does have a `time` data type, but that's designed for storing a time of day. As such, it doesn't support anything larger than 24 hours.

Comment: You are correct,  moments after submitting this question the light went on.  Thanks for the comment!!

Comment: ....The new release is _potentially_ SARGable, assuming it's 0-padded.  The only benefit to this new format is if the interval is "relative", that is, it's subject to DST ( a day isn't always 24 hours).  Which would be a pain to translate it a duration in seconds.  Otherwise, it's just problematic to add/subtract/whatever.  If it _is_ absolute, a numeric type would be better (and take half the space or less, depending on resolution).  For an absolute measure, this representation is solely a formatting problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different approach, by separating the days from the time part. Then, to transform in seconds, you could multiply the days by 86.400 (the number of seconds in a day) and convert the another part using time format 14 (look date/time formats [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) please)

Suppose a build schema like the following:

```
create table Tbl_Timespan (interval varchar(17))
insert into Tbl_Timespan values ('0003:23:12:36.042')
```

You can convert this column to seconds as:

```
select 
  interval,
  LEFT(interval,charindex(':',interval)-1)*86400+
  DATEDIFF(second,0,convert(varchar, replace(right(interval, len(interval) -    charindex(':',interval)),'.',':'),14))
from Tbl_Timespan
```

I am not handling with erros, and would be much better to work with functions to do so.

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/210c7/12/0)

Comment: This presumes that `hours` isn't larger than 23, but that seems probable in this case.  It also assumes that the interval is "absolute", in the sense that a day is always 24 hours (ie, not subject to DST).... which may not be.  Need more information from the op on that one.

Comment: The points described above are valid.  I found a potential workaround but I'm not sure if it's a great option.

Comment: DATEPART(HH, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(DATAFIELD, 
                      12))) * 3600 + DATEPART(N, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(DATAFIELD, 12))) * 60 + DATEPART(S, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(DATAFIELD, 12)))